# Update notifier doesn't work [cache issue]

Tags: update-manager, motd

The update notifier doesn't notify me when updates are available. Sometime ago I had a similar problem and this worked:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
```

But it does't work in this case:

```
sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force
E: Unknown error: «<class 'KeyError'>» ("The cache has no package named 'wine1.7-i386'")
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get auto-clean
sudo apt-get clean all
```

But it didn't work either.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
moray33@Jose:~$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
moray33@Jose:~$ sudo dpkg --audit
moray33@Jose:~$ dpkg -S /var/lib/apt/periodic/ /var/lib/update-notifier/
apt: /var/lib/apt/periodic
update-notifier-common, ubuntu-release-upgrader-core, update-manager-core: /var/lib/update-notifier
```

Comment: Why you removed those files????

Comment: They suggested me to remove them in order to solve a similar problem I had some time ago (and it worked).

Comment: Edit your qeustion and include the output of `sudo apt-get check` `sudo dpkg --audit` and `dpkg -S /var/lib/apt/periodic/ /var/lib/update-notifier/`

Comment: Output included.

Comment: Why are you trying to execute `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available`?

Comment: For testing if the update notifier icon shows up.

Comment: Are you running 14.04? I had this same error message a couple of days ago with a wine update on 14.04

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 4):

Hi I am new to ubuntu so I am trying it out, I got to know wine because I wish to use Dreamveaver but with no success, I even tried to install some .dll from winetrick and tried to remove some because apparently wine has made my computer into a "windows server"(that's what an error message said). Anyway after doing those things,I had the same problem as yours until this morning.

`E: Unknown error: «<class 'KeyError'>» ("The cache has no package named 'wine1.7-i386'")`

As I had "lost" wine1.7-i386, I tried to reinstall it so I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
```

then it updated my wine1.7 and wine1.7-amd64  and also installed wine1.7-i386.
hey also while downloading wine1.7-i386 it aborted for some forgotten reason.
but I retyped the same command and it continued. And now the error message is gone.
Hope that will help you.

---

PS: I never used `sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp` or and the rest.

Comment: I still see the error message after doing what you suggest. I tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7-i386` and I get the messages `wine1.7-i386:i386 is already the newest version.`, then `wine1.7-i386:i386 set to manually installed.`, then `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

What it worked for me is that I purged all Wine packages, and deleted all of these folders:
HOME/.wine
HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
HOME/.local/share/icons/
And then installed again Wine and it seems I have no longer this issue.

Comment: The issue came back again, so it's not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came t this solution. I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it. I tried upgrading wine1.7-i386 but it said I was at the latest version.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine1.7-i386
rm -r ~/.wine
sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=810815

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo ( apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade )
```

then log out and log in again.

Though see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/531248/why-is-there-a-persistant-apt-error-indicator-when-i-have-since-repaired-my-syst

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue.
I just run de command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and the problem solve by it self.